# writing part of an array to file in C++

Tags: c++

I want to write k elements starting from k*i to a file. so in a for loop I write as below:

```
    testOut.write((char*) h_test[k*i] ,k*sizeof(float));
```

I get this error "invalid cast from type ‘float’ to type ‘char*’ "

How should I correct this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to write them in binary, you can do as follows:

```
testOut.write( reinterpret_cast<const char*>(h_test + k*i), k*sizeof(float));
```

`h_test + k*i` is the address of a `float` pointer, that you reinterpret to a `const char*` so that `write` can take it. Note that adding to a pointer increments the pointer taking into account the pointed element size, and you convert the pointer *after*.

Finally, `write` accepts a `const char*`, not `char*`.

Answer (score 1):

I assume `write` takes a `char *` and a size. Try this:

```
testOut.write((char*)&h_test[k*i], k*sizeof(float));
```

`h_test` is probably an array of `float`s. You tried to dereference it like this:

```
h_test[k*i]
```

That's a `float`, not a `float *`. To make it a pointer, you use the `&` operator.